# Extract multiple element from BeautifulSoup within one Div

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract lon/lat information from a website using beautiful soup and with the code below get the mapdata BS4 element which contains the info I need. There can be one or more (two in the url below) lon/lat coordinates, so I am trying to find a way to correctly parse the string to extract the info.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://fire.wikia.com/wiki/Moose_Jaw_Fire_Department"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

mydivs = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "mapdata" })        
mydivs
```

This gives the following

> [{"minzoom":false,"mappingservice":"googlemaps3","type":"ROADMAP","geoservice":"geonames","types":["ROADMAP","SATELLITE","HYBRID","TERRAIN"],"maxzoom":false,"width":"auto","height":"350px","centre":false,"title":"","label":"","icon":"","visitedicon":"","lines":[],"polygons":[],"circles":[],"rectangles":[],"wmsoverlay":false,"copycoords":false,"static":false,"zoom":false,"layers":[],"controls":["pan","zoom","type","scale","streetview"],"zoomstyle":"DEFAULT","typestyle":"DEFAULT","autoinfowindows":false,"resizable":false,"kmlrezoom":false,"poi":true,"markercluster":false,"tilt":0,"imageoverlays":[],"kml":[],"gkml":[],"fusiontables":[],"searchmarkers":"","enablefullscreen":false,"locations":[{"text":"\u003Cp\u003ESouth Hill Fire Station\n\u003C/p\u003E","title":"South Hill Fire Station\n","link":"","lat":50.384617,"lon":-105.553335,"alt":0,"address":"","icon":"","group":"","inlineLabel":"","visitedicon":""},{"text":"\u003Cb\u003E\u003Cp\u003ELillooet Fire Station\n\u003C/p\u003E\u003C/b\u003E\u003Chr /\u003E\u003Cp\u003ENorth Hill Fire Station\n\u003C/p\u003E","title":"Lillooet Fire Station\n","link":"","lat":50.402969,"lon":-105.533991,"alt":0,"address":"","icon":"","group":"","inlineLabel":"","visitedicon":""}]}]

I attempted to get to the locations element within the BS4 element in which case I think I would have a json file I could use, but have not been able to find the line of code which would get me to that point.

Comment: I tried the following code thinking that I could search for the string of lon/lat but it just gives an empty result. `soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "mapdata" }, string="lon")`

Comment: `lat = json.loads(soup.find("div", { "class" : "mapdata" }).text)['locations'][0]['lat']` gave me the `50.384617`. could probably do similar for "lon". what do you think?

Comment: Awesome need to create a loop to pick it up, when there are multiple lon/lat but work well. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, glad to help, comment back if you need more help. Good luck!